# Around Lund in winter: will two italians survive?

Tags: italy, sweden, winter

We are an Italian couple and we are planning to go to Lund for the 1st of the year. We go visiting some friends and then we will stay some additional days in order to visit nice places around.

I know for instance that Copenaghen is probably one of the best places to visit (relatively) close to Lund. I also had a look on some Guides and on the Internet and I know there are parks and castles to visit in/nearby Lund.

**However the cold might be an issue for us**. I would like to know if during the winter most of touristic places (opened during the summer) are stillopen and enjoyable, and if compared to summer, everything is more difficult to enjoy due to the cold.

To be pragmatic:

- Does the temperature go very low?
- What we need to bring with us?
- Are common touristic (museums, amusement parks, etc) around closed/unreachable/difficult to enjoy due to the cold?

And most importantly:
Will we freeze? Will we survive? *Will we be sent back to Italy in a 1 cubic meter ice cube and then have to wait the ice to melt under the warm Italian sunrays?*

Comment: No, they will dump you in a field, wait for the ice to melt in the Spring and then send whatever remains are left back to Italy. It's much cheaper than shipping a 1 cubic meter ice cube.

Comment: Survive? Yes. Enjoy? That's another question.

Comment: Genetically, Italians are surprisingly similar to Danes (in rare circumstances, some have even been known to cross-breed). So given proper clothing, I see no reason why Italians should be more susceptible to freezing than the locals.

Comment: In all seriousness, though, your question seems to me to be too vague and/or opinion based. "is it worth it" questions are *always* off topic. Clearly it's worth it *to some people* (else nobody would do the thing), and not to others (else everyone in the world would do the thing). What specifically do you want to know? What is the low temperature during that time of year? Is it likely to snow? What should you wear? Are Danes friendly to Italians during winter?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't want to make a personal opinion-based question. I simply want to know if there are nice places to visit and enjoy, if during the winter they are closed (as in the case of parks) or if, compared to summer, everything is more difficult to enjoy due to the cold.

I try to edit the question accordingly, specifying my that the cold could be a problem.

Comment: Southern Sweden and Denmark are both oceanic climate.  Wiki tells me that the average temperature for Lund in January is around 0 or maybe higher, as compared with about -2 for, e.g., Boston, Massachusetts (a lot further South).  These are emphatically not dangerous temperatures if you have a reasonable coat.  If you want to do more things inside, though, maybe a larger city like Copenhagen is better.

Comment: If you can narrow your question to whether a specific place, or type of place (museums, amusement parks, etc) is closed, that would be on-topic. Asking if "nice places" are open is opinion-based, as everyone has a personal definition of "nice."

Comment: @Flimzy I just edited the question, I hope it works now.

Comment: @Flimzy in any case the "spirit" of my quesiton was close to the one of this question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/does-it-makes-sense-to-travel-to-iceland-during-winter?rq=1

Comment: @DanieleB: That's a *really old question*... I suspect it, too, would be closed if it were asked today (and now that you've brought attention to it, the old question may also be closed).

Comment: I have visited some great paleolithic sites in southern Sweden during the winter, and there's some superb hang gliding locales on the east coast about an hour and a half away from Lund. But it's hard to picture someone booking a trip with no clue about the locale. Close voting as opinion-based.

Comment: It's not cold there as pointed out in the replies already given, but if you ever go to a  cold place, you can deal with that by [dressing properly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OfEeO.jpg). And with [some special training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaMjhwFE1Zw) you can even survive for a while in ice cold conditions completely naked. You may want to follow [this YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzGLM3ieDWt1L3lPyIZNm2w).