# Is possible to visit all Iceland sights in April/May?

Tags: sightseeing, weather-and-climate, iceland

I have a couple of holiday weeks between the end of April and the first week of May and I'm wondering if Iceland is a good destination for that period. I've read that 2-3 weeks is enough to visit all the country's sights, so my idea is to visit each one, but I don't know if this will be possible or not due the snow level and other climatological issues.

Comment: [This is relevant](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1451/2708), and maybe even a duplicate as one of [the answers](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1458/2708) might answer your question. Let us know if the answers to that question lack something for your case.

Comment: I've read this question while looking for advice, but for me isn't relevant any of the 4 points there. I'm only interested in the accessibility, even if there are too much tourist, is cold or the hotels are more expensive. My holiday dates are very restrictive and I need to know if I'll be able to access to all Iceland sights or it will be better to go to Iceland on summer. Anyway, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "all sights". Iceland has a lot to offer and you could spend a whole summer there without seeing everything.

2-3 weeks is however ample to do a traditional "around the country" drive, traveling along the ring road (highway 1), hitting many (albeit not all) places of interest. Such a trip can be done in one week, so you'll have ample time for detours during a 2-3 week long trip.

Being late April/early May, any mountain road is likely to still be closed and many of the secondary roads may be in rough shape after the winter. This will limit you to sights that are reasonably close to the main highways.

At that time of year, you will find the weather will still be quite cold, making camping a less than exciting prospect. Also, some hotels/guesthouses are only operated during the summer, so you should plan ahead a bit on where you are going to be staying.